# Code compliance with 120/240v outlet

Tags: nec, 120-240v

I am updating the electrical in my garage. Right now, it has two GFCI 120v outlets, one on the outdoor outlets circuit and the other on the garage opener circuit. I am looking to add locking 240v outlets, and have two questions about it.

1. Can I install a NEMA 6-20 outlet, and connect a device shipped with a NEMA 6-15 connector, provided I change the connector to 6-20?

2. Can I install NEMA 14-20 outlets, and disregard the unused leg for different voltages? i.e. connect a plug to the outlet, and not wire the neutral to anything for 240, not wire anything to the second hot for 120.

Item 1 would be convenient because I wouldn't have to install both NEMA 6-15 and NEMA 6-20 outlets, and item 2 would be nice because I could wire 120v devices as locking with existing outlets.

EDIT: I'm talking about **locking** versions of these outlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking or not, it makes no difference.

1. Most likely yes you can. Provided the item does not stipulate that it must be on a 15A circuit.
2. No, you cannot install 14-20R receptacles and only wire some of the terminals, if that's what you mean. 
   Re-reading it I think you want to install the 14-20's normally and only use what you need as per each item. This would be OK.

Comment: Your assumption is true. But just to clarify, I would wire the receptacle normally, and use only the correct wires off the plug, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. As long as you wire the receptacle properly.